# Draw Ellipse in Python PIL with line thickness

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am trying to draw a circle on an image, using Python. I tried this using PIL but I would like to specify a `linewidth`. Currently, PIL draws a circle but the border is too thin.

Here is what I have done.

For a test image: I created a 1632 X 1200 image in MS Paint and filled it green. I called it **test_1.jpg**. Here is the input file:
[image: Input]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open('test_1.jpg')

width, height = im.size
eX, eY = 816,816 #Size of Bounding Box for ellipse

bbox =  (width/2 - eX/2, height/2 - eY/2, width/2 + eX/2, height/2 + eY/2)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
bbox_L = []
for j in range(0,5):
    bbox_L.append([element+j for element in bbox])
    draw.ellipse(tuple(bbox_L[j]), outline ='white')

im.show()
```

Basically, I tried to draw multiple circles that would be centered at the same spot but with a different radius. My thinking was that this would create the effect of a thicker line.

However, this is producing the output shown in the attached file below:
[image: Output]

**Problem:** As you can see, the bottom-left and top-right are too thin. Also, there are gaps between the various circles (see top left and bottom right).

The circle has a varying thickness. I am looking  a circle with a uniform thickness.

**Question:**
Is there a way to do draw a circle in Python, on an image like **test_1.jpg**, using PIL, NumPy, etc. and *to specify line thickness*?

Comment: Any thoughts here about suggested approaches to this? If any additional information is required, please let me know and I will update the original post.

Comment: I'd wish to know the answer too! Alas, I cannot help you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem, and decided to write a helper function, similar to yours. This function draws two concentric ellipses in black and white on a mask layer, and the intended outline colour is stamped onto the original image through the mask. To get smoother results (antialias), the ellipses and mask is drawn in higher resolution.

#### Output with and without antialias

[image: ellipses with PIL]

The white ellipse is 20 pixels wide, and the black ellipse is 0.5 pixels wide.

#### Code

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def draw_ellipse(image, bounds, width=1, outline='white', antialias=4):
    """Improved ellipse drawing function, based on PIL.ImageDraw."""

    # Use a single channel image (mode='L') as mask.
    # The size of the mask can be increased relative to the imput image
    # to get smoother looking results. 
    mask = Image.new(
        size=[int(dim * antialias) for dim in image.size],
        mode='L', color='black')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)

    # draw outer shape in white (color) and inner shape in black (transparent)
    for offset, fill in (width/-2.0, 'white'), (width/2.0, 'black'):
        left, top = [(value + offset) * antialias for value in bounds[:2]]
        right, bottom = [(value - offset) * antialias for value in bounds[2:]]
        draw.ellipse([left, top, right, bottom], fill=fill)

    # downsample the mask using PIL.Image.LANCZOS 
    # (a high-quality downsampling filter).
    mask = mask.resize(image.size, Image.LANCZOS)
    # paste outline color to input image through the mask
    image.paste(outline, mask=mask)

# green background image
image = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(700, 300), color='green')

ellipse_box = [50, 50, 300, 250]

# draw a thick white ellipse and a thin black ellipse
draw_ellipse(image, ellipse_box, width=20)

# draw a thin black line, using higher antialias to preserve finer detail
draw_ellipse(image, ellipse_box, outline='black', width=.5, antialias=8)

# Lets try without antialiasing
ellipse_box[0] += 350 
ellipse_box[2] += 350 

draw_ellipse(image, ellipse_box, width=20, antialias=1)
draw_ellipse(image, ellipse_box, outline='black', width=1, antialias=1)

image.show()
```

I've only tested this code in python 3.4, but I think it should work with 2.7 without major modification.

Comment: This answers my question.

Comment: For width > 1, I found the following change necessary to make the ellipse actually fit completely in the border: `for offset, fill in ( 0, 'white' ), ( width, 'black' ):`.

Comment: How would this work if I want to draw a circle with fill color?

Comment: @Stefan: Just draw the filled ellipsis first. Then draw the outline ellipsis.

Comment: @Håken Lid: I tried that but it looks good only if I increase the thicknes of the second elipse so as to completely owerwrite the first. That means I have to have some lines thicker than others ... also a second thing that I noticed is that now my drawings take up more memory, around three times more, than before ...

Comment: I'm using the above method for a cleaner looking ellipse and it's perfect. However my PIL drawing includes rounded corners and I'm sure I can see the tiniest bit of colour (blue my case) showing through, assuming it's the ellipse mask behind showing through here's a screenshot https://pasteboard.co/JxtnY6K.png but it's very hard to see but very annoying to me is there a way round this?

Comment: @James I can't tell what causes the blue colour there from just the image. You can post a new question and include your code, making it a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @HåkenLid I've opened a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555664/issue-with-border-color-of-image-in-pil) Kind regards.

Answer (score 6):

Simple (but not nice) solution is to draw two circles (the smaller one with color of background):

```
outline = 10 # line thickness
draw.ellipse((x1-outline, y1-outline, x2+outline, y2+outline), fill=outline_color)
draw.ellipse((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill=background_color)
```

Answer (score 2):

From version [5.3.0](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/5.3.0/) onwards, released on 18 Oct 2018, ***Pillow*** has supported `width` for [`ImageDraw.ellipse`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.ellipse). I doubt many people are using *PIL* nowadays.

Comment: This answer should be way, way higher.

Comment: is there a more modern alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to specify ellipse thickness, but you probably can draw lines at each pixel where ellipse pass, with the argument width=...

NB: I'm foreign, so sorry if my english is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `Image.core.draw` method like this:

```
zero_array = np.zeros((224,224))
im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(zero_array))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
dr_im = Image.core.draw(im.getdata(), 0)
dr_im.draw_rectangle((22,33, 150,100),220,2)
dr_im.draw_rectangle((22,33, 150,100),125,0)
#draw.rectangle((22,33, 150,100), fill=220,outline = 125)
print(np.array(im)[33][23])
im.show()
```

Comment: This only draws a couple of rectangles — so it is unclear what it has to do with drawing thick ellipses.