# Drawing in python: Why is my circle so ugly?

Tags: python, drawing, python-imaging-library

How can I smooth out the circle? At some points there are bumps and it's quite .. rough. I need to draw multiple circles inside and it really looked bad when I tried it. Is this some issue with PIL or something I miss?

Here is how I draw it:

```
import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

OUT_PATH = "" # of your liking
DRAW_CLR = (255,204,0)
DRAW_IMG_BCKG_CLR=(15,48,90)
w = h = 586
im = Image.new("RGB", (w, h), DRAW_IMG_BCKG_CLR)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

thick = 3
circlesize= min(w, h)
circle = circlesize*0.9
circle_bbox = (w/2 - circle/2 - thick, h/2 - circle/2 - thick, w/2 + circle/2 + thick, h/2 + circle/2 + thick)
draw.ellipse(circle_bbox , fill=DRAW_CLR)
im.save(OUT_PATH+"circle.png",DRAW_CHART_IMAGE_TYPE)
```

[image: circle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your circle appear smoother you need to add antialias.

Example with and without antialias:
[image]

Resource: [Draw Ellipse in Python PIL with line thickness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504246/draw-ellipse-in-python-pil-with-line-thickness)