# Mask of line in PIL

Tags: python, bezier

I've got this function, which draws a bezier curve:

```
from random import randint
from PIL import Image

def plot_curve(image, px, py, steps=1000, color=(0, 0, 0)):
    def B(coord, i, j, t):
        if j == 0:
            return coord[i]
        return (B(coord, i, j - 1, t) * (1 - t) +
                B(coord, i + 1, j - 1, t) * t)

    img = image.load()
    for k in range(steps):
        t = float(k) / (steps - 1)
        x = int(B(px, 0, n - 1, t))
        y = int(B(py, 0, n - 1, t))
        try:
            img[x, y] = color
        except IndexError:
            pass



n = 4

for i in range(0,10):
    coord_x = [randint(0, 999), randint(0, 999), randint(0, 999), randint(0, 999)]
    coord_y = [randint(0, 999), randint(0, 999), randint(0, 999), randint(0, 999)]

    image = Image.new("RGBA", (1000, 1000))

    plot_curve(image, coord_x, coord_y)
    name = '{:03d}'.format(i) + "_double_curve" + ".png"
    image.save("./train/" + name)
```

how would I return the co-ordinate mask of this line, say 10px either side? I've tried to do the same bezier curve but with a thicker line, but I cannot see how to set the width of the line and then save the co-ordinates?

Comment: What is the expected output for some (non-random) input? But I think there is no math solution; calculate the points left and right at right angles for each point per line segment.

Comment: As in the expected output of the function itself? It draws a bezier curve.

Comment: No, I mean the format of your coordinate mask.

Comment: What's a "mask of a line"?

Comment: Like highlighting it, eg. https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN - the masks are the coloured polygons over the objects of interest. If you see the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504246/draw-ellipse-in-python-pil-with-line-thickness the white area would essentially be like a mask and that's what I'm thinking I need to generate the co-ordinates of

Comment: Unless curve offsetting is already built in, this is an incredibly hard problem and unlike lines or circles, a Bezier curve [cannot be offset by a second, single Bezier curve](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#offsetting). It's actually a tremendous amount of work to compute the offset outline of a Bezier curve, so my advice would be "search the web for a Python library that does that for you, because someone must have already made one".

Comment: Mind you, if you _just_ want coordinates, then you don't need to actually get the offset curves, you just need the original curve. and then run through that curve, offsetting each point on the curve along the curve's normal for that point. See above link (section on normals) on how to do that. It's pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , yes realised I'd been over thinking it. And wrote the offset, does what I need it to now.